# how to send email message with php and html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send a message from HTML form. But for some reason I am not getting anything. Could someone please help me ?

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="subb.php">
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="Message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="Message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <button type "submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button submit">Send message</button>
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Message = $_POST['Message'];

    $to = "combatstriker111@gmail.com";
    $subject="new message";

    mail($to , $subject , $Message, "From :"  . $Name . $Email);

    echo "Your message has been  Sent";
?>
```

I have named the PHP file `subb.php` and listed them both in the same directories but its still not working for some reason. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In `subb.php` if you were to do `exit( print_r( $_POST, true ) )` before `mail` do you see expected data?

Comment: I suppose you have a submit button ?

Comment: `<button type "submit"` ~ missing `=`

Answer (score 1):

Something in your code was wrong `mail($to , $subject , $Message, "From :"  . $Name . $Email);`

[Mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function SYNTAX :

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

So,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];

    $Message = "Name : ".$Name."<br />"
    $Message .= $_POST['Message'];

    $to = "combatstriker111@gmail.com";
    $subject="new message";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: Name <$to>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:  $Name <$Email>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";


    if(mail($to, $subject, $Message, $headers)) {
       echo "Your message has been  Sent";
    } else {
       echo "Mesage Error";
    }  
}
?>
```

Note : Use any mail library for prevent vulnerable to header injection like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];;
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to      = 'info@fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com';
$subject = 'Message From Website';
$headers = 'From: info@fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: info@fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$themessage = "Name: ".$name."</br>Email: ".$email."</br>Phone: ".
            $phone."</br>Subject: ".$subject.
            "</br>Message: ".$message;
//echo $themessage;


if(mail($to, $subject, $themessage, $headers)){
 echo "message sent";
 header( 'Location: http://www.fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/contactus.php?smresponse=Message Sent' ) ;
 }else{
echo "we have a error charlie!";
}
;
```

test this out and if it doesn't work it means your hosting blocks mail function.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help - if it does send an email how will the OP know?

Comment: mail returns True or false so if($mail){echo "OMG IS WORKED"}else{echo "Error!");

Comment: i normally redirect with a header call and have a page grab the error and display on form. Add to code for you

Comment: ok thanks for the help , do you know where  i  can get a free hosting that supports mail function?

Comment: not for free, i give free sponsorship hosting for people learning though. Send me private message with email. Also what is it being used for?

Comment: info@fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com